# Elasticsearch 1.7.3 and Shield on docker

Tags: security, elasticsearch

I encountered a problem when i tried to secure my elasticsearch cluster (tried only with 1 node). The ES node it's on docker and when i tried to install shield and add an user it keeps giving me

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.shield.authc.esusers.tool.ESUsersTool
```

Here are the dockerfile commands

```
USER root

ENV ES_PKG_NAME 1.7.3
    # Install Elasticsearch.
    RUN \
      cd / && \
      wget https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-$ES_PKG_NAME.tar.gz && \
      tar xvzf elasticsearch-$ES_PKG_NAME.tar.gz && \
      rm -f elasticsearch-$ES_PKG_NAME.tar.gz && \
      mv /elasticsearch-$ES_PKG_NAME /elasticsearch 

    # Mount elasticsearch.yml config
    ADD config/elasticsearch.yml /elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

    ENV ES_JAVA_OPTS "-Des.path.conf=/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.logs=/elasticsearch/logs"


    RUN /elasticsearch/bin/plugin -install royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ && \
        /elasticsearch/bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/license/latest && \
        /elasticsearch/bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/shield/latest

    RUN ln -s /elasticsearch/config/shield /elasticsearch/shield
    RUN chmod +x /elasticsearch/bin/shield/*
    ENV PATH /elasticsearch/bin/shield:$PATH 
    RUN esusers useradd es_user -r admin -p pass

    # Define mountable directories.
    VOLUME ["/data"]


    # Define working directory.
    WORKDIR /data

    # Define default command.
    CMD ["/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch"]

    # Expose ports.
    #   - 9200: HTTP
    #   - 9300: transport
    EXPOSE 9200
    EXPOSE 9300
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think your `Dockerfile` is masking this error:

```
$ /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/shield/esusers useradd es_admin -r admin -p pass
ERROR: Invalid password...passwords must be at least [6] characters long
```

Try making your password longer than `pass`.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it.